# Dont show menu on register/login page in vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a side menu which i don't want to show in login/register page and I need to show it in almost all other pages. How do i go about it?

```
<div id="app ui container">
    <Menu/>
    <router-view/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are far better ways to handle this, but since you are not sharing your code you can use something like this:

```
computed: {
 hide () {
   return this.$route.path === '/login' || this.$route.path === '/register'; 
 }
}
```

Alternatively you can still use hide/show on the element itself as:

```
 <Menu v-if='this.$route.path !== "login" || this.$route.path !== "/register"'/>
```

but that is even far less recommended

Answer (score 4):

create a computed property like

```
showMenu() {
    return this.$route.name !== 'login' && this.$route.name !== 'register';
}
```

and add the `v-if="showMenu"` to your `<Menu/>`

Answer (score 1):

1. You should create a separate page for login and a separate folder for all other pages.
2. Provide logic for user authentication at Login page and for each successful login create a user session to navigate to user account home page.

Answer (score 0):

// router/index.js

```
{
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "login" */ '../views/Login.vue'),
    meta: {
      hideNavbar: true,
     }
  },
```

In App.vue your

```
<Nav v-if="!$route.meta.hideNavbar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

with `composition api`

```js
//routes/index.js
{
  // this named route, you then use in App.vue
  path: '/login',
  name: 'login',
  component: () =>
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "login" */ '../views/LoginView.vue'),
},
```

and App.vue

```js
<template>
<TheNavigation v-if="route.path != '/login'" />
<RouterView />
<TheFooter />

</template>

<script setup>
import { RouterView } from 'vue-router'
import TheNavigation from './components/TheNavigation.vue'
import TheFooter from './components/TheFooter.vue'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
const route = useRoute()
</script>
```